# Ubuntu 20 boot blocked, loading initial ramdisk

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dual-boot, initramfs, ubuntu-mate

I have just installed Ubuntu 20 Mate.
When I try to boot it, the process is blocked at `loading initial ramdisk`.
I already tried to reinstall it. What could be the problem?
I am using a Dell Inspiron 15 5567 with Intel i7-9700U, 16Gb RAM, AMD R7 M445 dedicated GPU.
These are my partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SanDisk X400 2.5
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8BF721E2-AA3C-43E8-A8B0-1B608E93C690

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2      34816 346265599 346230784 165.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  346265600 347469823   1204224   588M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda4  437407744 496001023  58593280    28G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  496001024 500117503   4116480     2G EFI System
/dev/sda6  435453952 437407743   1953792   954M Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

The first three partitions are related to Windows, including Windows Boot Manager.
Grub is installed in sda5.
I am using UEFI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the answers to [this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229910/ubuntu-20-04-black-screen-after-installing-no-booting), I disabled PPT security in the UEFI settings:

> For those who are new to the BIOS, press <kbd>F2</kbd> when you see the Dell logo, go to `Security` → `PTT Security` and uncheck `PTT On`. Click `Apply` (I would recommend choosing `Save as Custom User Settings`), then `OK`, then `Exit`.

Comment: So did this solved your problem?

Comment: @rubaiat yes, it solved my problem

Comment: How could a ubuntu distron have such complex setup to work ? Strange, no?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have PTT Security in my BIOS

Adding `dis_ucode_ldr` to grub helped in my case:

See: https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7540-will-only-boot-Linux-if-charger-is-connected/td-p/7449042/page/3

Comment: I have the booting problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04, but the default options for recovery mode already have dis_ucode_ldr, It also has: ro recovery nomodeset

Answer (score 1):

On an Lenovo IdeaPad 330s-15ikb, I upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04 after Ubuntu Software Updater prompted me to upgrade, but after the first reboot, my system would stop at "loading initial ramdisk." The kernel option `dis_ucode_ldr` was already in grub recovery mode, and `mitigations=off` did not help. Next, I booted from Ubuntu 21.04 in a USB, mounted my solid state drive, and ran `apt dist-upgrade` and `apt update`, but then I could boot only once and was back to where I started.

What helped was **updating my old Windows 10** (in my other partition) to 1909 and then 20H1. There may have been other firmware, microcode, or UEFI/BIOS updates, but I saw a **Lenovo firmware update** version 1.17.0.0 dated 3/23/2018. In the beginning, I had BIOS 7SCN17WW, while 7SCN36WW was available, but I did not verify it  updated.

Now Ubuntu 21.04 boots fine with zero changes to the Linux side.